# Does objective-C class store primitive type properties on heap?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have a custom class:

```
@interface someClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int intProperty;
@end
```

and it has a method:

```
- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"%p", &(_intProperty));
}
```

Execute the following code:

```
SomeClass* someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
someClass.intProperty = 3;
[someClass test];
```

The output is:

```
2016-12-05 19:42:33.001951 test[2316:881536] 0x17401d078
```

Looks like an address on the heap. But as we know, you can't store a primitive type variable on the heap. So how does it read an int from a pointer to a heap address?

Providing relevant links will be appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: A better test would be to add a few more properties to your class. Add another primitive or two. And add a pointer. Then look at the address of all of the properties (including the address of the pointer). They should all be in consecutive memory addresses once you take into account the size of each type.

Comment: @rmaddy I actually did that, they are all consecutive, but I still wonder if the primitive values are actually stored in these heap address or they are stored else where, for example the static section?

Comment: Yes, the value is at those addresses. Look at the bytes starting at a given property's address. For the `intProperty` address you will see the bytes `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03` (or possibly ordered the other way around) assuming a 32-bit int. You will see 8 bytes if it's a 64-bit int.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I wondered. I'll have a try. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Hampotato I think the "static section" you refer to is the data section where stores all initialized global variables, they are "static" while the `someClass` instance is allocated dynamically, so `someClass` is located in the heap. "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective" is a good book which elaborates all of this, I recommend you to read the `Linking` chapter : )

Comment: @KudoCC I'll definitely look into that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `SomeClass alloc` method, it allocates memory on the heap, the memory stores variables of `SomeClass` instance including `intProperty`.

We suppose you didn't use @synthesize to rename the instance variable of `intProperty`, so the backup variable of `intProperty` property is `_intProperty`.

`someClass.intProperty = 3;` this line of code stores 3 to the address of `_intProperty`. The compiler can figure out the address of `_intProperty` which is the address of `someClass` plus the a offset, the offset is the distance of the `_intProperty` variable address from the begin of `someClass`. As we know the address of `_intProperty`, we can read from it or write to it.

> But as we know, you can't store a primitive type variable on the heap

It's wrong, we can store a primitive on heap, the code below store a integer value on the heap.

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); // a is a pointer, its value is the address on the heap
*a = 4;  // store the value 4 to the address on the heap
free(a); // you must free the memory.
```